# Transition from wood laminate to concrete 3/8" down

Tags: concrete, laminate-floor, transition

What should I put down to transition  wood laminate to concrete floor 3/8" down?  Last owner did a DIY rehab it seems, and they just left a bare edge of the wood tile with a visible gap under it - looks tacky and I imagine is probably susceptible to problems.  I have a hardwood threshold but not dead set on using it - something thinner might make more sense given the step down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your run-of-the-mill reducer should do the job. This type usually comes with a steel channel that you'd anchor to the concrete, then you simply tap the piece in place.

[image]

Comment: Try not to secure a threshold transition strip directly to the laminate. The laminate needs room to expand and contract, Securing it fast to the subfloor or butting it tight to the wall or adjacent floor can cause buckling. The transition isherwood pictured is an excellent choice.